# fail to get api result by fetch (express)

Tags: node.js, typescript, fetch

I tried to fetch api by using express. However, I dont know why app.get cannot get any result. In browser, I have to so long...still have not get any result.

However, i run the api link on postman, it works fine to me. Do I miss everything??

```
import * as express from 'express'
import {Request, Response} from 'express'
import * as bodyParser from 'body-parser'
import * as path from 'path';
import fetch from 'node-fetch';


const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}))
app.use(bodyParser.json())


const PORT = 8080
app.listen(PORT, ()=>{
    console.log('listening to PORT 8080 ')
})


app.get('/', async function(req:Request,res:Response){
    try{
        await getResidentialData()
    }catch(e){
        console.log("error")
    }
})

async function getResidentialData(){
    const res = await fetch('https://api.coinbase.com/v2/currencies')
    const result = await res.text();
    return result
}
```

Comment: @ne1410s it just keeps loading and said This site can’t be reached...
postman also same behavior. However, I run the api link on postman, it works fine. should be the app.get issue but just dunno how to fix...

Comment: Have tried calling the `app.listen` at the very end? for me, it doesn't work because you're listening (starting the server) before any routes are defined. Try switching the order of the `app.get` and the `app.listen`

Comment: @Paul-LouisMas yes, I did switched now. However, the issue now turn to loading... for a long time without result send back. CAUTION: request has not finished yet!

Comment: Ok, I think I know what is the problem then, you are not sending data back with the response, you need at least a `res.json(await getResidualData())` and you need to add something to write to the response in the catch too

Comment: Btw, I think that your `getResidualData()` should be returning JSON using `await res.json()` (instead of `await res.text()`) because the Coinbase APi returns JSON data, no?

Comment: @Paul-LouisMas yes, I got it. I should write a response for that. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 2):

I feel `app.get` is not returning anything since it doesn't send any `response` back. To send a response back, its always best to use `res` object in your API call like so:

```js
app.get('/', async function(req:Request,res:Response){
    try{
        const result = await getResidentialData()
        res.status(200).send(result) //<----- add this
    }catch(e){
        console.log("error")
        res.status(400).send("Something went wrong") //<----- add this
    }
})
```